# XSLT: Selecting a value from a preceding-sibling of a following sibling/child node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My source XML file look like this:

```
<DocumentList>
<Document>
<ID>123</ID>
<SubID></SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>123</ID>
<SubID>1</SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>124</ID>
<SubID></SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>124</ID>
<SubID>2<SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>125</ID>
<SubID>1<SubID>
</Document>
</DocumentList>
```

From that XML file I want to create new XML file which will skip the first entry of the element for which another sibling is present in the XML file. My output XML file would be like this:

```
<DocumentList>
<Document>
<ID>123</ID>
<SubID>1</SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>124</ID>
<SubID>2<SubID>
</Document>
<Document>
<ID>125</ID>
<SubID>1<SubID>
</Document>
</DocumentList>
```

I've been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours. Please share some ideas.

Comment: Search for XSLT grouping. You can solve this with *Muenchian grouping* in XST 1.0 and `for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0. What happens when there are two `SubID` nodes? Do you keep just the last one? Or do you add the values, ignore the empty nodes, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Using XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="DocumentList">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Document" group-adjacent="ID">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[last()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hey @martin-honnenI have an issue with XSLT following sibling selection, can you please look at this [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897747/how-to-get-following-sibling-from-xml-using-xslt-from-child-node)

Answer (score 2):

using XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="DocumentList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Document">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ID = following-sibling::Document/ID"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Joel please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897747/how-to-get-following-sibling-from-xml-using-xslt-from-child-node