# How to get following sibling from xml using xslt from child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSL and XSLT and I have been trying to get the following sibling of my node but after trying several methods it is still not working.
I am using this `glyph/image/following-siblings::image[1]/path` to reference following sibling.

This is how my XML structured.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tablet id="A">
    <side id="Aa">
        <line id="Aa01">
            <glyph id="Aa01-001">
                <image id="Aa01-001-b" type="b">
                    <path id="path-1" d=""/>
                    <x>7.6107272</x>
                    <y>21.662689</y>
                    <width>52.389273</width>
                    <height>55.234216</height>
                </image>
                <image id="Aa01-001-f" type="f">
                    <path id="path-2" d=""/>
                    <x>9.9999</x>
                    <y>25.437278</y>
                    <width>34.33299</width>
                    <height>73.835859</height>
                </image>
            </glyph>
            <glyph id="Aa01-002">
                <image id="Aa01-002-b" type="b">
                    <path id="path-3" d=""/>
                    <x>58.25</x>
                    <y>21.41996</y>
                    <width>22.113771</width>
                    <height>75.019102</height>
                </image>
                <image id="Aa01-002-f" type="f">
                    <path id="path-4" d=""/>
                    <x>63.205795</x>
                    <y>24.00143</y>
                    <width>22.582803</width>
                    <height>74.659189</height>
                </image>
            </glyph>
    </line>
    </side>
</tablet>
```

And my XSLT looks like this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet PUBLIC "Unofficial XSLT 1.0 DTD" "http://www.w3.org/1999/11/xslt10.dtd">

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

 <!--  Main template  -->

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tablet"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Tablet -->

 <xsl:template match="tablet">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="side"/>
 </xsl:template> 

 <!-- Side -->

 <xsl:template match="side">
  <h2>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="side-name"/>
  </h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="line"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Line -->

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <xsl:variable name="curLine" select="line-num"/>
  <h3>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
   <xsl:text>Line </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="line-num"/>
  </h3>
  <xsl:call-template name="drawGlyphLine"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Glyphs-->

 <xsl:template name="drawGlyphLine">
  <p>
   <xsl:text>Glyphs: </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="count(glyph/image[@type=$display-type])"/>
  </p>
  <div>
   <xsl:attribute name="height">
    <xsl:value-of select="160"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="width">
    <xsl:value-of select="svg-width[@type=$display-type]"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="glyph/image[@type=$display-type]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Glyph image -->

<xsl:template match="glyph/image">
 <svg>
     <g>
        <xsl:copy-of select="glyph/image/following-siblings::image[1]/path"> <!--Here I want previous sibling of path-->
        </xsl:copy-of>
     </g>
     <g>
     <xsl:copy-of select="path"> <!-- This line is making the output a copy of path-->
     </xsl:copy-of>
     </g>
     <g>
        <xsl:copy-of select="glyph/image/preceding-sibling::image[1]/path"> <!--Here I want next sibling of path-->
        </xsl:copy-of>
     </g>
  </svg>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output, I want the following sibling of a current path. I have not added the full code cause of not making it unnecessarily long. Basically, full code automatically makes a copy of the path and renders the SVG. Now I just want the next and previous sibling.

Now the output should be like this.

```html
<svg>
  <!-- previous path node -->

  <path id="path-1" d=""/>
  <x>7.6107272</x>
  <y>21.662689</y>
  <width>52.389273</width>
  <height>55.234216</height>

  <!-- next path node-->
</svg>
<svg>
  <!-- previous path node -->
  <path id="path-2" d=""/>
  <x>7.6107272</x>
  <y>21.662689</y>
  <width>52.389273</width>
  <height>55.234216</height>
  <!-- next path node -->
</svg>
<svg>
  <!-- previous path node -->
  <path id="path-3" d=""/>
  <x>7.6107272</x>
  <y>21.662689</y>
  <width>52.389273</width>
  <height>55.234216</height>
  <!-- next path node -->
</svg>
<svg>
  <!-- previous path node -->
  <path id="path-4" d=""/>
  <x>7.6107272</x>
  <y>21.662689</y>
  <width>52.389273</width>
  <height>55.234216</height>
  <!-- next path node -->
</svg>
<svgg>
  <!-- previous path node -->
  <path id="path-5" d=""/>
  <x>7.6107272</x>
  <y>21.662689</y>
  <width>52.389273</width>
  <height>55.234216</height>
  <!-- next path node -->
<svg>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output of the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated the question, is it enough to have the answer, or should I upload complete code?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that includes an input, your attempted code and the exact expected output - as code, not as a description (which I, for one, do not understand). --- Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: While code I get the first path which has an id="path-1", I also want to have the following path which has an id="path-2"

Comment: let me just add the complete code maybe, then I can explain better.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have added the question with more details and complete code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Why are you using `following-siblings` when you want the preceding sibling? and *vice versa?*

Comment: I want bot following and preceding sibling.

Comment: that's the typo, actually wrote that while posting and wrote wrong, however in both ways output is empty nothing showing up there. @michael.hor257k

Comment: Could you please update the wanted result in a way that it resembles the input?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I'll try, I just want the copy of the previous <path> tag. and the following tag.

Comment: It is not clear to me what preceding-sibling you need if the current node is this: <image id="Aa01-002-b" type="b">

Comment: if the current node is `<image id="Aa01-002-b" type="b"><path id="path-01">` I also want following sibling if have any like this. `<image id="Aa01-002-b" type="b"><path id="path-02">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has unique image IDs. However, if you want to traverse forwards and backwards, you can use the `preceding` axis. That is, if it is not causing any performance issues.

In your `glyph/image` template, store the `@id` first in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="curr_id" select="@id"/>
```

then use that as you traverse in either preceding or following axis

```
 preceding::image[@id=$curr_id][1]/path
 following::image[@id=$curr_id][1]/path
```

Your template should look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="glyph/image">
    <xsl:variable name="curr_id" select="@id"/>
    <svg>
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="preceding::image[@id=$curr_id][1]/path"> <!--Here I want previous sibling of path-->
            </xsl:copy-of>
        </g>
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="path"> <!-- This line is making the output a copy of path-->
            </xsl:copy-of>
        </g>
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following::image[@id=$curr_id][1]/path"> <!--Here I want next sibling of path-->
            </xsl:copy-of>
        </g>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>
```

I have modified your example in the following link (http://xsltransform.net/pPgCH6G). That should do it if my assumptions are right.

Answer (score 1):

In this template

```
<xsl:template match="glyph/image">
 <svg>
     <g>
        <xsl:copy-of select="glyph/image/following-siblings::image[1]/path"> <!--Here I want previous sibling of path-->
        </xsl:copy-of>
     </g>
     <g>
```

the context item is an image element, so the selection of glyph/image is wrong. You just want `<xsl:copy-of select="following-siblings::image[1]/path">`

Comment: Do note that in the given example not all `image` elements are siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
  <xsl:template match="image">
    <svg>
      <xsl:copy-of select="preceding::image[1]/path"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following::image[1]/path"/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
```